# ¿Cómo permitir solo letras del alfabeto y espacios en un JTextField? - Java

Tags: java, jtextfield

Tengo un campo en la cual el usuario pueda ingresar su(s) apellido(s), si el usuario desea ingresar sus dos apellidos el software debería permitirle colocar espacios, pero el siguiente código que tengo no me deja colocar espacios, una ayuda por favor:

```
private void JTXTFApellidosKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                        
    final char keyChar = evt.getKeyChar();
    if (!(Character.isAlphabetic(keyChar) || (keyChar == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) || keyChar == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE)) {
        evt.consume();
    } else if (Character.isLowerCase(evt.getKeyChar())) {
        evt.setKeyChar(Character.toUpperCase(evt.getKeyChar()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo que utilices el método `Character.isWhitespace(keyChar)` en lugar de las constantes VK, ya que la misma documentación dice que no es recomendable el uso de estas constantes.

Dejo el enlace de la documentación:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html

Comment: ¿Por qué no es recomendable? Deberías de agregar en la respuesta la razón y con la fuente. Esto hace que la respuesta sea de calidad.